# jQuery collapsable element implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery and wanted to find out if this is a good implementation of a jQuery collapse:

```
$(function () {

    var collapse = {
        "body" : $(".collapse-body"),
        "container" : $(".collapse-container"),
        "trigger" : $(".trigger"),
        "show" : $(".is-collapse"),
        "speed" : 300
    };

    function isCollapse() {
        return $(collapse.body).hasClass("is-collapse");
    }

    function isCollapseSingle() {
        return $(collapse.container).hasClass("collapse-single");
    }

    function collapseShow() {
        if (isCollapse()) {
            collapse.show.show();
        }
    }$(document).ready(function(){collapseShow()});

    //
    $(collapse.trigger).click(function (id) {
        id.preventDefault();
        var atv = $(this).attr("href");
        $(atv).slideToggle(collapse.speed);

        if (isCollapseSingle()) {
            $(collapse.body).not(atv).slideUp(collapse.speed);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: is it functioning as you expected?

Comment: @Wycliffe peart  Can you post your html code too?I would suggest you to use either the Jquery or javascript in your code?